# Uzing Azure VMs as test agents to drive a load test to a site outside of the Azure cloud

Tags: performance, testing, azure

I am trying to overcome load balancing issues on a test site.  Has anyone used mulitple instances of Azure VMs as test agents to drive a load test to a site outside of the Azure cloud?  Using VMs with IP switching from within commercial data centers works but its expensive.  I have set up agent servers in two data centers and inside our enterprise.  I am looking to see if I can create a single solution that can run tests to externally facing test sites.  I welcome any other thoughts on this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have done so. There is "only" one limitation - you only get 1 (single) public IP Address Address per cloud service deployment. So if you have 10 VMs into single Cloud Service (also known, or referred to as to `hosted` service) all these 10 agents will hit the site as single IP Address. This is something really worth considering.

Other then that your scenario is fully valid and feasible, but not subject to a simple Stack Overflow answer.

You may want to take a look [at this article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/How-to-provision-a-Visual-55a3538a#content), which might give an idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a solution from Visual Studio Online which can help you in this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/07/08/wip-cloud-load-testing-with-visual-studio-online.aspx

Give a look at this.